# Does the Olympus OM-D E-M10 II use the same battery as the previous version?

Tags: olympus, olympus-omd

I would like to purchase a OM-D E-M10 II and I want an extra battery with it. Does it use the same battery as the previous version, the OM-D E-M10?

Does it come with an external battery charger?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they both use the same battery type. The E-M10 comes with a BLS-5 and the E-M10II comes with a BLS-50. They are equivalent as you can see in [Power Supplies for OM-D / PEN series cameras](http://www.olympus.co.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/compati/pen_power.cfm). You can buy replacement batteries for the E-M10 and they'll work for the E-M10II.

Both come with a BCS-5 battery charger that can charge both batteries

Comment: Both dpreview.com and the Olympus product pages say that the OM-D E-M10 uses a BLS-5, while the OM-D E-M10 II uses a BLS-50. Is that a typo that just got repeated? Or are these two batteries compatible?

Comment: They are compatible. Look here : http://www.olympus.co.jp/en/support/imsg/digicamera/compati/pen_power.cfm

Comment: Might want to edit to include that info, as well as the fact that the cameras both come with a BCS-5 battery charger.

Comment: @J. Pablo Fernández - Thank you for cleaning my answer, and if it's good please mark it :)